# Exclamation mark in Keys enum

Tags: c#, winapi, enums

there is `Keys` enumeration in `.NET` `(System.Windows.Forms.Keys)`, but I can't find `Exclamation` mark(!) and colon(:), what about it? Or is there a way to automaticly transform letters to `Keys` enum, without `Enum.TryParse`? Thanks for help, FanAs.

Comment: Well, does the usual event fire when you press those keys? If so: what is the value of the arg?

Comment: I don't have a `!` or a `:` key.

Comment: On a Belarussian keyboard you have to press Shift+1 to get "!" and Shift+6 to get ":".  The point of Keys is that it is language-independent, it represents virtual keys that are the same anywhere in the world.  Good odds that you should be using the KeyPressed event, it reports the resulting keystroke after converting the virtual key and the active modifier keys to a character code.

Answer (score 2):

Colon (:) it's the combination of two keys, depending on the configuration keyboard. So maybe you should detect the combination pressed at the same time. Idem for !: Shift + 1

Answer (score 1):

They are in the `Oem` category of `Keys` like `Keys.Oem1` and so on.

You have to check for special Keys press also like Shift for finding your characters.

Answer (score 1):

For exclamation points it is actually a combination of the Shift key and the digital 1 (D1) key. so it looks like

```
  if(e.KeyCode == Keys.D1 && (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
```

So it is not a result of an Oem key.